# Updating table using dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

In the following table, "ColumnDifference":

[Screenshot of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3ETP.jpg)

each cell in "ColumnName" is the name of a column in another table, "regressionDifferences". I have to select each of the columns listed in ColumnName from regressionDifferences, matching on UniqueID, and insert the first eight characters in each string into ColumnContent.

So far I have:

```
DECLARE @LoopCounter INT = 1, @MaxRowNumber INT = 420,
@ColumnName VARCHAR(max), @UniqueID VARCHAR(max), @ColumnContent VARCHAR(max), @SQL VARCHAR(max), @table VARCHAR(max)

WHILE(@LoopCounter < @MaxRowNumber)
BEGIN
SELECT @ColumnName = ColumnName
FROM ColumnDifference WHERE RowNumber = @LoopCounter

SELECT @ColumnContent = ColumnContent
FROM ColumnDifference WHERE RowNumber = @LoopCounter

SELECT @UniqueID = UniqueID
FROM ColumnDifference WHERE RowNumber = @LoopCounter

SET @sql = 'UPDATE ColumnDifference
SET ' + @ColumnContent + ' = (SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(' + @ColumnName + ',0,9) FROM regressionDifferences rD 
WHERE rD.UniqueID LIKE '''
                  + @UniqueID + '%'')'

exec(@sql);

SET @LoopCounter = @LoopCounter + 1

END
```

If I set @sql to:

```
'SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(' + @ColumnName + ',0,9) FROM regressionDifferences rD WHERE rD.UniqueID LIKE ''' + @UniqueID + '%'''
```

I get the correct results but all in separate tables:

[Screenshot of SELECT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3uRc.jpg)

And if I print the original @sql I get a blank message box.

When executed I get "Command(s) completed successfully" but nothing at all changes in ColumnDifference. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Before the `exec(@sql);` place `PRINT @sql` and check what the actual content in the `@sql`. More over you are adding `WHERE` clause to the `SELECT` statement only. So the `UPDATE` executes for all the entries in the table.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I do that nothing appears in the message box at all. If I set @sql to `SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(' + @ColumnName + '0,9) FROM regressionDifferences rD WHERE rD.UniqueID LIKE ''' + @UniqueID + '%'')'` it gives me the results but it gives each one in a separate table in the message box. I don't know if this could be the problem?

Comment: You probably don't need dynamic SQL.  This approach is working row by row, which undermines SQLs set based approach.  If you could add sample source data, and the output you would expect from that sample, we can probably help refactor this query,

Comment: Ok thanks, I updated my original question to include more information

Comment: What @destination-data said. There is no need for looping and dynamic sql here. This could be rewritten as a single update statement. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Also, looking at your sample data you will never actually do anything here because the value of @ColumnContent will always be NULL. And why oh why are you using a datetime as "uniqueID"?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the update if this provides you the desired result:

```
DECLARE @LoopCounter INT = 1 , @total as  int , @colname as varchar(10) , @sql as nvarchar(1000)

--- getting the max no of rows
set @total =(select count(*) from 
(select cd.ColumnName, row_number ()over(order by rd.UniqueID) as rw  from regressionDifferences rd
inner join ColumnDifference cd on rd.UniqueID = cd.UniqueID)t)


WHILE(@LoopCounter < @total)
BEGIN

--- select one row at a time
set @colname = (select t.ColumnName from (select cd.ColumnName, row_number ()over(order by rd.UniqueID) as rw  from regressionDifferences rd
inner join ColumnDifference cd on rd.UniqueID = cd.UniqueID)t
where t.rw=@LoopCounter)


SET @sql = 'SELECT SUBSTRING(' + @colname + ',0,9) FROM regressionDifferences rD'

exec(@sql);

SET @LoopCounter = @LoopCounter + 1

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a problem with `SET ' + @ColumnContent'`. See how it should be. That should work:

```
DECLARE @LoopCounter INT = 1, @MaxRowNumber INT = 420,
@ColumnName VARCHAR(max), @UniqueID VARCHAR(max), @SQL VARCHAR(max), @table VARCHAR(max);

WHILE(@LoopCounter < @MaxRowNumber)
BEGIN
SELECT @ColumnName = ColumnName
    , @UniqueID = UniqueID
FROM ColumnDifference WHERE RowNumber = @LoopCounter;

SET @sql = 'UPDATE ColumnDifference
SET ColumnContent = (SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(' + @ColumnName + ',0,9) FROM regressionDifferences rD 
WHERE rD.UniqueID = ''' + @UniqueID + ''')';

PRINT @sql;
exec(@sql);

SET @LoopCounter += 1;

END
```

I've also fixed initial select: You do not need to extract `@ColumnContent` at all (or do you?).
I've took away `LIKE`: There is `UniqueID`, it must be unique, NO LIKE.
Some other small changes.